# Cannot start MySQL with XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am trying to start mysql with XAMPP without success. The Apache works fine, but when the mysql try to start show  Couldn't start MySQL!

here is the log

```
130408 11:07:05 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /u01/lampp/lampp/var/mysql
130408 11:07:05 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130408 11:07:05 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130408 11:07:05 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use InnoDB's own implementation
130408 11:07:05 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130408 11:07:05 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130408 11:07:05 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130408 11:07:05 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130408 11:07:05  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130408 11:07:06 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
130408 11:07:06 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
130408 11:07:06 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130408 11:07:06 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130408 11:07:06 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: No such file or directory
130408 11:07:06 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock ?
130408 11:07:06 [ERROR] Aborting

130408 11:07:06  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130408 11:07:06  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
130408 11:07:06 [Note] /u01/lampp/lampp/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

130408 11:07:06 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /u01/lampp/lampp/var/mysql/JOOMLA.pid ended

in my.cnf says:
socket      = var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simply `Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: No such file or directory`, which means you don't have correct path set or configured path doesn't exist or you don't have sufficient privileges.

Check if there exists directory structure that the mysql expects and that the user you use to run mysql has sufficient privileges on this directories. Files *.sock and *.pid shouldn't exist when the mysql is stopped.

Comment: Supposing the path to socket /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock is correct. Does this file exist even if the mysql is stopped? It could remain here after unsuccessful shutdown or kill or whatever. Being there it prevents mysql from starting.

Also is the listening port 3306 unused?

Does the path where the socket is created exist? Looks like that kind of problem.

Comment: solved, i created the specified path and works fine. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: glad to help :)